# How to find address from the Census BlockCode?

Tags: united-states, census, address

I have Census BlockCode information (15 digits) and need to get corresponding street name and address in NYC. What is the best source of such information?

Comment: I think that this is a question better researched/asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

NYC should have a data warehouse that will have census block information. If it were me I would probably find that data and make a nice map with point locations through QGIS, but I just looked it up real quick and found this link.

http://maps.nyc.gov/census/

You can look up census tracts or by address, and make sure to zoom about 50% of the way to view the census tract numbers.

Census data is something that is open to the public, I am from San Diego and we have an organization called SANDAG that houses all of the public GIS data. There should be a government website to reach that can fit your solution if this link above doesn't

Comment: The track is bigger then a block code (it has 15 figures) and I need to get hundreed of addresses (so I'm looking for some dB or script).